# Get the correct text-color and font-weight

Tags: css, colors, fonts

I am trying to design this button [image]

according to this image [image] (Only image source exists.)

Applying changes to the code

Html

```
<a href="#">Community</a>
```

CSS

```
#topbar ul li a { 
background-color: #6293F0; 
color:  #D6EA68;
}
```

The result is [image]

The issue is to get 1) correct text-color, 2) font-weight.

I get a different text-color each time I use a different color picker.
Example: These are the color codes from different color picker for yellow text-color : #D6CD45,  #D6EA68,  #D4E160,  #F3FF9C,  #C8D762, #F4F766.

How should i solve this issue?

Comment: It looks as though there is a shadow on the text.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, it seems that I missed the shadow. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: As you have basically discovered, there is no concept of text color. In this low def image lots of different colors can be seen. You could try taking a lot of color picker readings and take the average, but to be honest you are as likely to get a good match by doing it by eye. Different screens will show colors subtly differently anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
a { 
  background-color: rgb(100, 145, 239); 
  color:  rgba(234, 255, 46, 1);
  text-shadow: -2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  padding: 30px 30px;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Community</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping it in div?

```html
<div class="box"><a href="#">Community</a></div>
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #6293F0;
}

.box a {
  color: #D6EA68;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```